# Getting Error when using SQL With Common Table Expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL. I am trying to use SQL CTE but I keep getting the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I am using ms-sql and reading the following [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stored-procedure-with-common-table-expression-or-cte/) for guide.

This is my query

```
WITH parents(BranchCode, SOLD,BANKERSCOUNT, [TARGET]) AS
(
    SELECT          MS.ParentBranchCode, 
                    SUM(NP.SOLD)  SOLD, 
                    SUM(NP.BANKERSCOUNT)  BANKERSCOUNT, 
                    SUM(NP.[TARGET]) [TARGET]
    FROM            NEDLLIFEPARTICIPATION NP
    INNER JOIN      m_Structure MS
    ON              MS.BranchCode = NP.BranchCode
    GROUP BY        MS.ParentBranchCode, NP.Year, NP.MONTH, NP.ProductId
)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have 16 lines, so it probably doesn't contain the error.  Do you have a `select` following this?

Comment: You need a `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc after that CTE. That statement isn't complete. Do we have the full query here?

Comment: Incidentally, you do not need to repeat the column list in the CTE declaration if the columns already have the names you want.

Comment: I must admit, that CTE seems odd. You're grouping by 4 columns, but only referencing 1 of them in the `SELECT`; meaning it's likely you're going to get a lot of rows for the same value of `MS.ParentBranchCode`. Why not just just group on the one column?

Comment: Try adding a `;` before the `WITH`. If there are preceding statements that can be required,

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator @PeterSmith, not a "beginningator". It goes at the end of the (previous) statement. Plus the error would have been very different if they had failed to terminate their **previous** statement.

Comment: all the previous lines are commented out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this give you an error? If not then it might be that you simply have not included a select statement following your common table expression. This would explain why your error is showing an issue with the closing bracket, it is just telling you (if my assumption is right) that your CTE is not being used in a query (and therefore will not compile).

```
WITH parents(BranchCode, SOLD,BANKERSCOUNT, [TARGET]) AS   
(
    SELECT          MS.ParentBranchCode, 
                SUM(NP.SOLD)  SOLD, 
                SUM(NP.BANKERSCOUNT)  BANKERSCOUNT, 
                SUM(NP.[TARGET]) [TARGET]
    FROM            NEDLLIFEPARTICIPATION NP
    INNER JOIN      m_Structure MS
    ON              MS.BranchCode = NP.BranchCode
    GROUP BY        MS.ParentBranchCode, NP.Year, NP.MONTH, NP.ProductId
)

select * from parents;
```

Comment: I have to use the parents table on another CTE, how do I handle such a case?

Comment: I would use the query from your CTE to generate a temporary table or table variable. that can be called repeatedly throughout the batch. Alternatively you could use that query to create a view which can be called multiple times by multiple batches. If it needs to be 2 CTES then you can place a comma after the closing bracket and then declare your second CTE without the "with".

Comment: My current problem requires recursion and I thought CTE where the right tool for that. But I am satisfied with your answer.

Comment: You're looking for a recursive common table expression @TiisetsoTjabane? Your question doesn't give that impression at all.

Comment: @Larnu I beginning to right my query with I started getting the error. willl post another question regarding how to do recursion with CTE